# Details of calibration of Hull-White model

Tags: yield-curve, calibration, forward-rate, hullwhite, short-rate

Consider the one-factor Hull-White model

$$
\mathrm{d}r(t) = (\theta(t)-\kappa r(t))\mathrm{d}t + \sigma\mathrm{d}W(t)
$$

When one calibrates the model to market data one chooses

$$
\theta(t) = \frac{\partial f^M}{\partial T}(0,t) + \kappa f^M(0,t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2\kappa}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-2\kappa t}\right)
$$

where $f^M(0,T) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\log(P^M(0,T))$ with the observed bond term structure $P^M(0,T)$ at the time of calibration.

I have several questions regarding this calibration:

- How do I come up with this formula for $\theta(t)$? I always read that this aligns the model with the market's zero curve. How can you derive that this formula in fact establishes the desired consistency?
- How do I come up with $P^M(0,T)$ and $f^M(0,T)$? Am I right that the following approach is taken?

  1. First the zero curve $y^M(t)$ is bootstrapped using coupon bearing instruments.
  2. The bootstrapped curve is just given at a finite number of points given by the maturities of the considered instruments. We interpolate these points (e.g. via spline interpolation) to obtain the function $y^M(t)$ on a continuous domain.
  3. Now we obtain $P^M(0,T)$ by setting $P^M(0,T) = \exp(-y^M(T)T)$.
  4. In a final step we compute the derivative $f^M(0,T):=-\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\log (P^M(0,T)) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(y^M(T)T\right) = -\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial T}y^M(T)\right)T - y^M(T)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question: the equation for $\theta(t)$ is obtained from the consistency condition 
$$
\forall T, \;\; E\left[e^{-\int_0^T r(t) dt} \right] = P^M(0,T)
$$
after a somewhat involved calculation using the integrated version of the SDE for $r$ 
$$
r(t)=e^{-\kappa t}r(0) + \int_0^t e^{-\kappa (t-u)} \theta(u) du + \int_0^t e^{-\kappa (t-u)} \sigma dW(u)
$$

Regarding your second question yes you bootstrap the zero curve on the choosen instruments, bonds or swaps depending on the market you are modeling. You may choose splines, or any other type of interpolation as long as the required derivatives can be computed.

As a sidenote if you define $x(t) = r(t) - f^M(0,t)$ then the SDE for $x$ is 
$$
dx(t) = \left(-\kappa x(t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \kappa}(1- e^{-2 \kappa t})\right) dt + \sigma dW(t)
$$
Thus when doing MC simulation or finite differences schemes you can use $x(t)$ as the state variable, and then simply add $f^M(0,t)$ to obtain $r(t)$, so that in fact you do need to compute $\frac{\partial f^M(0,t)}{\partial t}$, which means that zero curve interpolation methods that are not twice differentiable but only once differentiable (such as linear on yield or linear on log discounts) will produce $P^M(0,T)$ and $f^M(0,t)$ that can still be used with the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yet, there are some open questions remaining: You just said that the first point in the approach described is correct. What about the other steps? Secondly, regarding your sidenote: Where do I need the function to be twice differentiable? There is only one derivative appearing? And what is the advantage of using $x(t)$? I don't get your point there.

Comment: 1) all the steps in your approach are correct. 2) For computing $\theta(t)$ you need $\frac{\partial f^M(0,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln(P^M(0,t))) = -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \ln(P^M(0,t))$. This is why working with $x(t)$ is generally better, as there is no need to compute $\frac{\partial f^M(0,t)}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Sorry, I’m new to interest models and still not sure if I get your second comment so let me summarize what I understand: You want to compute $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f^M(0,t)$. One approach would be to calculate $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f^M(0,t) = -t\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}y^M(t)-2\frac{\partial}{\partial t}y^M(t)$ following the forth step in my approach. This would require our interpolation $y(t)$ to be twice differentiable. Another approach now would be:

Comment: $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f^M(0,t) = -\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2}\log\left(\mathbb{E}\left(\exp(\int_0^t r(s)\mathrm{d}s)\right)\right)\approx 
-\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t^2}\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\exp\left(\int_0^t r_i(s)\mathrm{d}s \right)\right)\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\sum_{i=1}^n r_i(t) =\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i(t)+f^M(0,t)) \approx \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathbb{E}(x(t)+f^M(0,t)) $

Comment: Where $r_i(t)$ and $x_i(t)$ are sample paths generated using MC. The last derivative can then be computed using MC sensitivity schemes like pathwise derivatives of likelihood ratios. Am I right there?

Comment: No it is much simpler. If you work with the SDE for $r(t)$ you need $\theta(t)$ and thus you need $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f^M(0,t)$. If instead you work with the SDE for $x(t)$ then you never need to compute $\theta(t)$. This is why most implementations of H&W work in the $x$ domain rather than in the $r$ domain.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: As I started to implement the approach mentioned in your sidenote another few questions came up :D 
1. With your approach I can sample paths of the Hull-white model without explicitely computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f^M(0,t)$. Hence, I can use this approach to price financial products using a Monte Carlo approach once I have calibrated the parameters $\kappa$ and $\sigma$ and bootstrapped the curve $f^M(0,t)$. 
2. Is the model also used to calibrate the parameters? For example by Monte Carlo pricing the market products using different parameters and choosing the best set of parameters

Comment: The main reason for the model popularity is that it has explicit formulas for vanilla products such as caps/floors, bond options, and swaptions, so that calibration to these products quoted prices can be done efficiently, and then the model can be used for non vanilla products. See any interest rate modeling book for more details.